# PHP - Comparing every two values of an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare

I have a multidimensional array which contains integer values. For example:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 ) ... and so on.
```

What I want to do is to compare every two elements from the array(from the first level of the array). BUT there is a catch. Let's take the first two elements(0 and 1): First I want to compare their first pair key-value(the values in the example are 0 and 2) and after that  the second pair key-value should be comared(in the example - both 1).

The output should be(for the first pair):
first element - [0, 1]
second element - [2, 1]
In the first comparison the script should return false(0 is not equal to 2), but in the second one it should return true (1 = 1).

I don't actually have an idea how to do that. I've tried to make it three dimensional(with `array_chunk`) but it's not working and I think I'm just making my life harder this way.

Either way, I'm posting the code for the three-dimensional version.

```
$tmpBig = array_chunk($indexArr,2);
for ($i=0; $i < count($tmpBig); $i++) { 
    print_r($tmpBig[$i]);
}

foreach ($tmpBig as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
            //echo $tmpBig[$key][$key2][$key3];
            //echo "<br>";
            if ($tmpBig[0][0] === $tmpBig[1][0]) {
                echo "yes";
            }else echo "no";
        }
    }
}
```

Every suggestion is welcomed and appreciated!

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: _Im not sure I'm explaining it right._??? Unclear what you want.

Comment: For a starter a simple Yes or No will be enough.

Comment: Yes/No to what? There is no question.

Comment: where's the question, `comared`?

Comment: Yes if any item of array is equal another?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about it all - If the values are both 0 (or like the second pair - both 1) to print Yes(or No if that's the case).

Comment: If the pair at position 0 is the same as a pair at position 5, should it be regarded as a match, or do the pairs need to sit next to each other?

Comment: Next to each other. First and second, third and fourth, fifth - sixth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will return for all elements the "duplicate" content they have at the same indices as their predecessors.

It relies on [`array_intersect_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) for checking if two arrays have any content in common at the same indices. It so, the result will be a non-empty array. These results are collected and should be what you need.

Here is the function you could use:

```
function findDuplicates($data) {
    $prev = [null];
    foreach($data as $i => $vector) {
        $same = array_intersect_assoc($vector, $prev);
        if (count($same)) $duplicates[$i] = $same;
        $prev = $vector;
    }
    return $duplicates;
}
```

You would call it as follows with some sample data:

```
// Sample data
$data = [[0, 1], [2, 1], [4, 3], [3, 1], [3, 1], [4, 3]]; 
$duplicates = findDuplicates($data);
```

If you `print_r` the result, you would get this for the sample data:

```
Array (
    [1] => Array ( [1] => 1 )    
    [4] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 )
)
```

This code also works for sub arrays with more elements than just 2.

Comment: It work perfect if I wanted the whole element to be compared. The first element([0, 1]) and the second([2, 1]) - should return one false(for example)  as 0 and 2 are not equal, but should return true for 1 and 1. The point is not to be compared the whole element. Hence my attempt with the three dimensional array.

Comment: That was not so clear from your question. I will update in a minute. Could you provide in your question an example of the output you need.

Comment: I corrected a mistake in my revised answer. The code should use the `array_intersect_assoc` function instead of what I had before. Sorry about that glitch.

Answer (score 0):

with the array `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 )` given as `$array`

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < count($array[$i]); $j++) {
        if($array[$i][$j] == $array[$i - 1][$j]) {
            echo "(" . $i . ", " . $j . ") and (" . $i - 1 . ", " . $j . ") are the same<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

This will also work with subarrays bigger then 2

What it does:
given a 2 dimensional array:
it checks if two following rows have the same number in `(x, y), (x - 1, y)`
It does that for each following rows

If you want to do it for each possible combination of rows:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array) - 1; $i++) {
    for($j = $i + 1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
        if($i != $k { //Lets not compare a row with itself
            for($k = 0; $k < count($array[$i]); $k++) {
                if($array[$i][$k] == $array[$j][$k]) {
                    echo "(" . $i . ", " . $k . ") and (" . $j . ", " . $k . ") are the same<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the comparison to be between the first and second element, the third and fourth, fifth - sixth... That's the whole problem.

Comment: The script given would compare it like so:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 )

1 == 3
2 == 4
5 == 7
6 == 8

Comment: My output from the first script is every row with the previous one. And from the second script(after notice for undefined variable $k) is every row with all the others. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach using simple `foreach` loop and `sprintf` function:

```
$arr = [[0, 1], [2, 1], [4, 3], [3, 1], [4, 1], [4, 5]];

foreach ($arr as $k => $item) {
    if ($k % 2 != 0) {  // perform comparison at each second item
        $prev_key = $k - 1;
        $prev = $arr[$prev_key];  // previous item
        $msg = "items at positions: %d and %d have the same value for the %d%s element. Value: %d". PHP_EOL;
        if ($item[0] == $prev[0]) echo sprintf($msg, $prev_key, $k, 1, 'st', $item[0]);
        if ($item[1] == $prev[1]) echo sprintf($msg, $prev_key, $k, 2, 'nd', $item[1]);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
items at positions: 0 and 1 have the same value for the 2nd element. Value: 1
items at positions: 4 and 5 have the same value for the 1st element. Value: 4
```